# what should I do[Shared Preferences]

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save 2 variable when application stopped and I want to use these variables when application restarted.I'm using sharedpreferences but I couldnt solve.

```
protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        for(int k=0;k<=secili.length;k++){
            if(secili[k]!=0)
            cevapdizisi[k]=secili[k];
        }

        for(int m=100;m>=0;m--){

            if(m!=0){
                sonsoru=m;
                break;
            }
```

in onStop there isnt problem

```
 @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        setContentView(R.layout.answerpage);

        txtquestion.setText(questions[sonsoru]);
        rdiogroup.check(secili[sonsoru]);

    }
```

in onRestart can't accessing txtquestion and rdiogroup.I'm created them on OnCreate.What should I do.I cant created them again onRestart.it will absurd.there must be another way.I need a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store values in shared preferences you may use following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

SharedPreferences prefs;
EditText edTextName,edTextPassword,edTextServer;


protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
.
.
//do your stuff...
.
prefs= this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
String hostname =   prefs.getString("HostName", null);
String name =   prefs.getString("UserName", null);
String password = prefs.getString("Password", null);



}

protected void onStop() {
.
//do your stuff...
.
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("HostName", edTextName.getText().toString());
editor.putString("UserName", edTextPassword.getText().toString());
editor.putString("Password", edTextServer.getText().toString());
editor.commit();

}


}
```

Comment: `onPause()` would be a better choice than `onStop()` for most uses.